# Execute dynamically created function in another scope

Tags: python, code-generation, code-inspection

I have got dynamically created funcion which accesses variable from another scope. For example:

```py
def dynamically_generated_function():
    print(x)  # x is not defined in scope visible to this function
```

I would like to execute that funcion, but variable x comes from diffrent place. I have got access to scope of that place via proper frame from `inspect.stack()`

I see 2 solutions to achieve that:

1. How to inject f_locals and f_globals from that frame to current frame?
2. How to execute dynamically_generated_function within frame that has variable x defined?

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamically generated function"? You can use `exec` or `eval` as appropriate and pass the appropriate local and global scopes as arguments, but that's probably not the best way to solve your problem.

Comment: I worked on creating a retry using contextmnager (retry done in __exit__). This is possible in 3.11, because FrameInfo contains information about the position of the contexmanager body .

The idea was to extract filename, lineno and end_lineno of cm body. I open the file, get the lines of code and execute these lines. Previously to fix IndentationError I created a fake function with this body and I have tried to execute it. But it was better to fix indentation, compile code object and call exec on it (as you've suggested)

Comment: You're trying to do this to implement a retry context manager? That's not going to work - you'll run into problems with weird NameErrors and assignments undoing themselves. Modifying a function's local variables through `exec` is undefined behavior. There's a reason the standard library doesn't already have a retry context manager in it.

Comment: But it works quite well :)  I've abandoned any modyfications of function variables. Just get body of contextmanager and execute it via exec with locals and globals from cm body frame.